# Typesafe Activator will not run for a second time

Tags: typesafe-activator

This is my first time using Typesafe Activator. I am using version 1.0.13 in Windows 7 64

I successfully created a JAVA_HOME in Environment Properties. 
Navigating to my Activator folder I successfully ran activator.bat and my terminal window opened and ran the loading code until `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` opened and I was in Typesafe Activator.

I noticed the terminal window was still open, and decided I wanted to clear my workspace so I closed it, not realizing Activator needed it to run.

After I restarted Windows, I opened activator.bat, and it checks for an update and then closes not launching Typesafe Activator. I am not sure what is wrong or how to get it running again.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and has successfully found a solution to get it to run again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the file RUNNING_PID, and you will be able to get the application to run again.